# Add letters to data in datatables

Tags: javascript, datatables

I receive data with this format:

```
var options = {
    "dom": '<t"bottom"lp>',
    "scrollY": "400",
    "scrollCollapse": true,
    "paging": false,
    "searching": false,
    "info": false,
    'columns': head,
    'data': tableModal,
    "lengthChange": false,
}
```

tableModal come from PHP but I would like add letters after the data, in this case "s" because the data are seconds, but I don't know how to do it.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Do you mean you want to edit one of the values of the json? (meaning the "tableModal" inside the "data" key?)

Comment: I want edit all the values because all are time's data

Comment: how about options.data = options.data + 's';

Comment: Where? Inside and outside I use this and the browser return a fail with format problem: "Requested unknown parameter".

Comment: Within your `head` you need to add a `render` function to the relevant column. Perhaps if you showed us your `head` array?

Comment: Oh yes, I have been testing and this works: 'render': function(data){
              return paintTmp(data);
            } where "paintTmp" is a function whith the new format
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

how about this

```
var options = {
    "dom": '<t"bottom"lp>',
    "scrollY": "400",
    "scrollCollapse": true,
    "paging": false,
    "searching": false,
    "info": false,
    'columns': {s:'s'},
    'data': [1,2],
    "lengthChange": false,
}

options['datas']=options['data']
delete options['data']
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/NVxX4udI5vqNvQyiZcdo?p=preview) example.
Below is the code snippet performing this operation of adding S.

```
function appendS(){
    $.each(options.data, function(index, data){
      options.data[index] = options.data[index]+'s';
    })
  }
```

If you are using this data on charts, please use appropriate formatter instead of going for this approach.